# Error 500 after Redmine migration

Tags: redmine

I´ve setup a new **Redmine 2.5.1** installation on **Ubuntu 12.04** with apache2 and passenger following this how to: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step

After that I´ve

1. dumped the mysql Database of an existing Redmine 1.1.3.stable
   installation,
2. restored it to a new DB at my new Server,
3. copied the attachements from old server to new server to
   **/usr/share/redmine/files** (+ chmod 755)
4. told redmine to use the newly created database with my old imported tickets in database configuration.
5. changed dir to /usr/share/redmine and fired this actions

> ```
> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production 
>
> rake generate_secret_token
> ```

So far so good. Redmine can be viewed in Browser, Administration settings can be changed an Projects a there.

But if I try to create a new ticket or view an old ticket I get an error 500. Besides this Redmine gives me Version 1.1.3 but should be 2.5.1. It seems I probably forgot to run a migration script.

[image: Error 500]

To find the error I´ve created

1. /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log
2. chmod 755 production.log
3. changed the error handling in my apache2 configuration

> ```
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
> LogLevel WARN
> ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/redmine-error.log"
> CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/redmine-access.log" common
> ```

But I can´t see any errors in production.log, redmine-error.log, error.log!?

How can I fix the error 500 problem?

**UPDATE** I handled to get logging running. Here is the Log output:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'author' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `workflows` WHERE (`workflows`.old_status_id = 1 AND (role_id IN (1) AND tracker_id = 1 AND ((author = 0 AND assignee = 0) OR author = 1))) ):
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:324:in `execute'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:639:in `select'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:81:in `cache_sql'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:60:in `find'
  app/models/issue_status.rb:78:in `find_new_statuses_allowed_to'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
  app/models/issue.rb:471:in `new_statuses_allowed_to'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:325:in `build_new_issue_from_params'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:225:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:629:in `run_before_filters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in `call_filters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:418:in `start_request_handler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:358:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:184:in `safe_fork'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:354:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:262:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:256:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:154:in `spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
  /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:61
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem could be solved by giving the tmp dir chmod 755